# My dialog is working online but its not working in offline

Tags: android

I have a list of company and I am opening a dialog for login the particular company. This is working fine online. Now my requirement is to move this app offline as well. And When i am clicking on a particular row of list i am getting crash and throw InflateExeption when app is offline. 
This is my dialog method.

```
public void showDialog(){
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_login);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    EditText username = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cusername);
    EditText password = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cpassword);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.remember_password);
    LinearLayout submit = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
    LinearLayout close = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < appUser.companyLoginArray.size(); i++) {
        Map map = appUser.companyLoginArray.get(i);
        String position = (String) map.get("position");
        if (pos == Integer.parseInt(position)) {
            Boolean status = (Boolean) map.get("status");
            String uName = (String) map.get("username");
            String pass = (String) map.get("password");
            if (status) {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                username.setText(uName);
                password.setText(pass);
            }
        }

    }
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            appUser.boolSetOrAddtoMap=false;
            appUser.company_logo=data.get(pos).getAttributes().getLogo();
            appUser.company_state=data.get(pos).getAttributes().getState();
            LocalRepositories.saveAppUser(context,appUser);
            Map mapAdd= new HashMap();
            if (!username.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                if (!password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    appUser.cusername = username.getText().toString();
                    appUser.cpassword = password.getText().toString();
                    LocalRepositories.saveAppUser(context, appUser);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {


                        mapAdd.put("position", String.valueOf(pos));
                        mapAdd.put("username", username.getText().toString());
                        mapAdd.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                        mapAdd.put("status", true);

                        for (int i=0;i<appUser.companyLoginArray.size();i++){
                            Map mapGet=appUser.companyLoginArray.get(i);
                            String str= (String) mapGet.get("position");
                            Integer integer= Integer.valueOf(str);
                            if (integer==Integer.valueOf(pos)){
                                LocalRepositories.saveAppUser(context,appUser);
                                appUser.companyLoginArray.set(i,mapGet);
                                LocalRepositories.saveAppUser(context, appUser);
                            }
                        }
                        if (!appUser.boolSetOrAddtoMap){
                            appUser.companyLoginArray.add(mapAdd);
                            LocalRepositories.saveAppUser(context, appUser);
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < appUser.companyLoginArray.size(); i++) {
                            Map mapRemove = appUser.companyLoginArray.get(i);
                            String position = (String) mapRemove.get("position");
                            if (pos ==Integer.valueOf(position)) {
                                appUser.companyLoginArray.remove(i);
                                LocalRepositories.saveAppUser(context, appUser);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventOpenCompany(pos));

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Enter username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: You should post logcat output. The layout infilation is not related with internet, its all related with your code. You should check your code for not doing internet operations or firebase operation while offline

Comment: yes Sir i know layout inflation is not related with the net connectivity. But Really i am getting shocked with the fallowing error.   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: But this code is running in network connectivity.

Comment: It looks like your XML file contains non-exists view types. Are you sure that you inflating the same layout while the app is offline on online? Because error says inflator tried to inflate unknown class.

Comment: yeah i am 100%  sure about that you asked? Actually i write the code in a method and i am calling the same method for offline and online.

Comment: You should share more code section, these codes are not enough to see the problem.

Comment: Sir how can i show our complete code ?

Comment: Okay, you can add full-logcat error output.

Comment: Process: com.lkintechnology.mBilling, PID: 1342
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: Sir how can i put up my complete code or complete error from logcat because comment section has limited size of character...

Comment: You can use pastebin? But I just want to see the exact crash log from the logcat, not all the logcat output.